# Equal Columns jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been working on a site that I need equal columns for. I am using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 (function() {
    function equalHeights(selector) {
      var maxHeight = 0;

      function calcEqualHeight() {
        var el = $(this);
        maxHeight = el.height() > maxHeight ? el.height() : maxHeight;
      }

      selector.each(calcEqualHeight).height(maxHeight);
    }

    equalHeights($('.exampleclass1'));
    equalHeights($('.exampleclass2'));
  })();
</script>
```

Trouble is, sometimes when the page loads, the heights don't always work correctly and content overlapped. I am wondering how I can change this to calculate the heights on page load?

Comment: Did you check the console?

Comment: Yes checked console, no errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use JS to do CSS' job.

```css
.column1 {background-color: #fcc}
.column2 {background-color: #cfc}

.columns {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.columns>div {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column1"><p>Short column</p></div>
  <div class="column2">
    <p>Tall column</p>
    <p>Look at how tall I am!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: flex is a great solution!

Comment: Thank you for your advice :-)

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to wrap selector with jQuery like this `$(selector)`
Please change this

```
  selector.each(calcEqualHeight).height(maxHeight);
```

to this

```
return $(selector).each(calcEqualHeight).height(maxHeight);
```

also use `return`  and let me know if it doesn't work!

EDIT: CSS flex is a great solution, By just apply `display: flex;` to parent it will make its child elements to have same height like below:

```
<style> 
   .parent{
       display: flex; 
   } 
</stlye>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="chid"></div>
   <div class="chid"></div>
</div>
```